# Global Transaction Handling in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

Its a Spring Integration application.I have a requirement where I need to persist to DB and then post to Queue/Topic. This should be part of a single transaction.  I am planning to use the JTATransactionManager. Application Server is Tomcat. Would someone please provide some sample configuration code required for this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You need a third party stand-alone XA transaction manager such as Atomikos. Tomcat doesn't have one.

You might also consider [alternatives to using full-blown 2pc](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html).

Comment: I have a Spring org.springframework.jms.connection.JMSTransactionManager and com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource  for JMS and DB resp. How do I configure them with Atomikos.

Comment: [This](http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/SpringIntegration) is the first search result when you google `atomikos spring configuration`.

Comment: I don't want to use a XA transaction manager like atomikos. Is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: As I said, read the [Dave Syer JavaWorld article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html) about alternatives to XA. Best effort 1PC is often used with Spring.