# How to make the flow transactional?

Tags: spring-integration

I am using a JMSTrnsactionManager which is able to read a message from a Queue and persist DB and then post the message to a Queue/Topic. when there is a failure in any of the gateays/ adapters I want to rollback the entire transaction and also rollback the data from DB. I am using Spring Integration framework with Message-driven-channel-adapter for reading from the queue and outbound-gateways for persisting to DB and outbound-adapters to post to topic. Datasource used is CombopooledDataSource. How to execute all of the above in a single transaction?

Answer (score 1):

You should not use a `JmsTransactionManager` on the inbound adapter - if you wish to synchronize the DB transaction (ala `Best Effort 1PC` in the article I pointed you to in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044375/global-transaction-handling-in-spring-integration)), you should add the JDBC Transaction manager to the message driven adapter. You need to also set `acknowledge="transacted"` on the adapter.

The outbound JMS adapter will automatically use the same transacted session on which the message is received.

Adding the JDBC transaction manager to the message driven adapter will synchronize the DB transaction with the JMS transaction (commit it immediately before the JMS transaction).

Comment: Thanks Gary , I will try this approach.

Comment: I tried this approach and see that the DB transaction rolls back . However the message does not end up on the ErrorQueue .It simply gets dequeued.

Comment: Why would you expect it to be on an error queue? It will be rolled back onto the original queue. Please show your complete configuration and explain in more detail your exact scenario.